# C# custom DateTime.ParseExact date string

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am trying to parse date's out of a database to a DateTime object.
The date's are formatted as the following: `5-5-2017 12:00:00` which is `day-month-year Hour:Mins:seconds`

Some more date's:

```
5-5-2017 12:00:00
5-5-2017 12:00:00
19-4-2017 0:00:00
19-4-2017 12:00:00
20-4-2017 0:00:00
20-4-2017 12:00:00
21-4-2017 0:00:00
21-4-2017 12:00:00
22-4-2017 0:00:00
22-4-2017 12:00:00
23-4-2017 0:00:00
23-4-2017 12:00:00
24-4-2017 0:00:00
24-4-2017 12:00:00
19-4-2017 0:00:00
```

I am trying to parse them with the following code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Shift_Data["shift_start_time"].ToString(), "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`Shift_Data["shift_start_time"]` contains the date (a single date because it loops through once for every date)

I am getting the following error:
[image: Error]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and/or why my custom date string is wrong (`"d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The conversion is correct, there is something else happening.
You can try this to see;

var dts = "5-5-2017 12:00:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dts.ToString(), "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: storing date without timezone information isn't right. store it with timezone info, say UTC and interpret it in the right way. your question is answered already but thought of making you aware of timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem are these dates `19-4-2017 0:00:00`. They only have a single-digit hour, but your date string `d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss` expects two.

Use `d-M-yyyy H:mm:ss` instead.

Relevant documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-h-custom-format-specifier-1

Comment: If i Respone.Write(moment.ToString()); I get the result: `1-1-0001 0:00:00`
Do you know why it is reset to the first possible date though? hmm

Comment: @RickStandaert I can't make a diagnosis without seeing where moment comes from and the code around the `Response.Write`. You should create a new question for a new problem.

Answer (score 2):

You sometimes have only one hour digit in your input:

```
19-4-2017 0:00:00
```

But the format

```
d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

requires always two hour digits (`HH`). Use

```
d-M-yyyy H:mm:ss
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string input, string[] inputFormats)
{
    string[] formats = null;
    if(inputFormats == null)
    {
        formats = new string[4];
        formats[0] = "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        formats[1] = "dd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        formats[0] = "d-M-yyyy H:mm:ss";
        formats[1] = "dd-M-yyyy H:mm:ss";
    }
    else
    {
        formats = inputFormats;
    }

    DateTime output;
    IFormatProvider provider = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID, true);
    output = DateTime.ParseExact(input, formats, provider, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
    return output;
}
```

You can add any format you want to support in `inputFormats` list. Also set the culture as per your need.

Call like this:

```
DateTime dt = ConvertToDateTime(Shift_Data["shift_start_time"].ToString(), null);
```